# How does Airflow decide to render template values?

Tags: jinja2, airflow

I am working with Airflow 2.2.3 in GCP (Composer) and I am seeing inconsistent behavior which I can't explain when trying to use template values.

When I reference the templated value directly, it works without issue:

```py
ts = '{{ ds }}' # results in 2022-05-09
```

When I reference the templated value in a function call, it doesn't work as expected:

```py
ts_parts = '{{ ds }}'.split('-') # result ['2022-05-09']
```

The non-function call value is rendered without any issues, so it doesn't have any dependency on operator scope. There are examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf#upload_a_dag_to_your_environment) that show rendering outside of an operator, so I expect that not to be the issue. It's possible that Composer has setting configured so that Airflow will apply rendering to all python files.

Here's the full code for reference
`dag.py`

```py
with DAG('rendering_test', 
    description='Testing template rendering',
    schedule_interval=None,   # only run on demand
    start_date=datetime(2020, 11, 10), ) as rendering_dag:

    ts = '{{ ds }}'
    ts_parts = '{{ ds }}'.split('-')
    literal_parts = '2022-05-09'.split('-')
    
    print_gcs_info = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_rendered_values',
     bash_command=f'echo "ts: {ts}\nts_parts: {ts_parts}\nliteral_parts {literal_parts}"'
    )
```

I thought that Airflow writes the files to some location with template values, then runs jinja against them with some supplied values, then runs the resulting python code. It looks like there is some logic applied if the line contains a function call? The documentation mentions none of these architectural principles and gives very limited examples.

Answer (score 4):

Airflow does not render values outside of operator scope.
Rendering is a part of task execution which means that it's a step that happens only when task is in the worker (after being scheduled).

In your code the rendering is a top level code which is not part of operator templated fields thus Airflow consider it to be a regular string.

In your case the `os.path.dirname()` is executed on `'{{ dag_run.conf.name }}'` before it was rendered.

To fix your issue you need to set the Jinja string in templated fields of the operator.

```
bash_command=""" echo "path: {{ dag_run.conf.name }} path:  os.path.dirname('{{ dag_run.conf.name }}')" """
```

Triggering DAG with `{"name": "value"}` will give:

[image]

Note that if you wish to use f-string with Jinja strings you must double the number of `{ }`

```
source_file_path = '{{ dag_run.conf.name }}'                   

print_template_info = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_template_info',
    bash_command=f""" echo "path: { source_file_path } path:  os.path.dirname('{{{{ dag_run.conf.name }}}}')" """

)
```

**Edit:**
Let me clarify - Airflow template fields as part of task execution.
You can see in the code base that Airflow invokes [`render_templates`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e82a2fdf841dd571f3b8f456c4d054cf3a94fc03/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1555) before it invokes `pre_execute()` and before it invokes [`execute()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e82a2fdf841dd571f3b8f456c4d054cf3a94fc03/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1598). This means that this step happens when the task is running on a worker. Trying to template outside of operator means the task doesn't even run - so the step of templating isn't running.

Comment: `Rendering is a part of task execution` This means that there is code substitution performed since the DAG objects are already created? Or is the templating performed against source files?

Updated my question to clarify things a little. I understand how to get the templated values to work within an operator, it's just not clear what's really taking place when the template is rendered

Comment: You wrote in your edit "There are examples here that show rendering outside of an operator, so I expect that not to be the issue" - I don't see any such example in the link you shared.

Comment: The templated value for `BashOperator` `bash_command` is passed in at the top-level dag definition [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/triggering-with-gcf#upload_a_dag_to_your_environment). I think the detail that's being elided in this example is that `bash_command` is included in `template_fields` within the operator definition. Is there somewhere that documents how/when these template fields are inspected/rendered? I guessed it was based on the actual source file, but that's clearly wrong and there's no documentation explaining otherwise.