# How to get conf value from airflow dag?

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I want to get conf value from dag area.

`"{{ dag_run.conf['company'] }}"` is recognized as a string.

How can I get this value?

Values ​​are passed fine when calling other dags.

```py
t_trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="t-trigger",
    trigger_dag_id="example_dag",
    conf={
        "company": "{{ dag_run.conf['company'] }}",
    },
)
```

However, in the dag area the value is recognized as a string.

```
t_task_a = PythonOperator(
    task_id="t-task-a",
    python_callable=task-a,
)
employees = Variable.get(
    "{{ dag_run.conf['company'] }}", # problem
    default_var=['company'],
    deserialize_json=True
)
for employee in employees:
    t_employee_operator = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f"t-test-operator",
        python_callable=employee_operator,
        op_kwargs={"employee": employee}
    )
    t_task_a >> t_employee_operator
```

Comment: You should not use `Variable.get()` in top level code as this is very abusive. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68257891/14624409  for reasoning why.

Comment: As for templating. You can not template outside of operators templated fields. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72137494/14624409

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed Airflow does not render templates outside of Operators scope - this is expected. You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72137494/14624409) for more information about it.

Furthermore you are using `Variable.get()` as top level code which is very abusive. I explained the reasons in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68257891/14624409).

I would suggest to redesign your DAG structure to fit Airflow DAG writing practices.